# How can i change appium configuration when it is installed by npm?

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install, appium-ios

I'm using `Appium version 1.5.1` in `Mac OS`.
I want to change appium configuration when it is installed by npm command (`npm install -g appium`) not by the .dmg application.
Is there a way to change it like changing the device name, command timeout, platform version ... ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there is any difference in set up if we install by npm or .dmg ?

Comment: yes in my case i want to use only appium npm, so there is a difference (cannot find the whole configuration i did in dmg in npm mode )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i change the default configuration for appium by this way :

> appium --default-capabilities
>   '{"app":"safari","browserName":"safari","appium-version":"1.5.1","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"9.3","deviceName":"iPad Air","nativeInstrumentsLib":true}' --command-timeout "0" --pre-launch
>   --nodeconfig "/Users/me/nodeconfig.json" --launch-timeout "180000"

Answer (score 2):

In 1.4.13, if u use dmg the path was

```
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/resources
```

but after install 1.5.1 using node, the path is

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/
```

i also have installed 1.5.1 using node and i also have previously installed 1.4.13 using dmg. In my case the problem was

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
```

i just comented this capability for when i run 1.5.1 by using command

```
appium
```

I use the 1.4.13 inspector to inspect(don't launch the appium 1.4.13), just click on inspector of it.

I also change this two line when i run my java code through command line in version 1.5.1

```
CommandLine command = new CommandLine("/usr/local/bin/node");
command.addArgument("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js", false);
```

In 1.5.1, instead of

```
driver.findElementByname(), use driver.findElementByAccessibilityId().
```

however, i set appium ios capabilities like below

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPad 2");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "7.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,"Mac");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

    capabilities.setCapability("sendKeyStrategy","setValue");
    capabilities.setCapability("--no-reset", false);

driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact i'm not using java i'm using it with protractor, otherwise i can't make a general config i should make it always in my config.js file ?

Comment: i don't use protactor, but u can start appium server by "appium" command and in ur code if u use the appium location, than just change the location with the new loaction.

Comment: i'm testing an url with safari, in fact when i launch appium the url is opened in the safari of ipad simulator than no thing happens it is blocked here so that i want to verify if i'm doing the right config !
socket data received got result from instrumetns {status : 0, "value":false } no alert found

Comment: as url is opened, so i think appium is running properly with 1.5.1. Actually when u start appium, it will show u a message in console that appium version ******* is starting...first check that u r using 1.5.1 than in ur code check that u r not using driver.findElementByname() method..... best is just debug....problem is in ur code.... :)

Comment: The problem my code is fine i even delete all the code for locating element just opening the site by browser.get() ..., then the test isn't passed !

Comment: i also use mac...but i can debug.

Comment: i didn't use it before in vi mode, but i'll try ;)